# Update child page's column in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Please see the following code:

```
public void UpdateChildPagesReWrittenUrl(int parentPageId)
    {
        var childPageList = db.PcPages.Where(m => m.ParentID == parentPageId);

        if (childPageList.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in childPageList)
            {
                db.ExecuteNonQuery(string.Format("UPDATE pcPage SET Url = {0}/{1} WHERE PageID = {2}",
                    GetRootUrl(item.ParentID),
                    hnUrlHelper.UrlSafe(item.PageName), item.PageID));
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

    }
```

I trying to update all the child pages url when a parent page updates the page name itself. This code I thought it working. but not.  Anyone can advise better in better way  please ?

Comment: why you don't just update the url property of the item? what's your reason for executing t-sql ?

Comment: The idea was I want to get rid of the foreach loop. I like to update the whole list (EG. where parentId =  parentPageId {para})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
public void UpdateChildPagesReWrittenUrl(int parentPageId)
{
    Func<PcPage, string> url = item => String.Format("{0}/{1}",
        GetRootUrl(item.ParentID), hnUrlHelper.UrlSafe(item.PageName));

    Array.ForEach(db.PcPages.Where(m => m.ParentID == parentPageId).ToArray(),
        x => { x.Url = url(x); });

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code above.  Now, I have a new issue: the above code solves this  1) HomePage/Homepagechild 2) Homepage/homepagechild2 . When I have : HomePage/Homepagechild/homepagegreatchild,  the homepagegreatchild is not being updated.

Comment: @coder - Sounds like a new question is in order. Let me know when you post it so I can have a crack.

Answer (score 0):

Is it updating anything ?  Can you use SQL Profiler to see what queries are actually sent ?

Could also set a breakpoint and make sure it is doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add quotes around new url address:

```
"UPDATE pcPage SET Url = '{0}/{1}' WHERE PageID = {2}"
```

Also I believe you can update child rows without fetching them

```
var query = @"UPDATE pcPage SET Url = Concat(ParentID, '/', PageName)
              WHERE ParentID = " + parentPageId; 
db.ExecuteNonQuery(query);
```

Comment: It should :) I think you will be surprised with performance difference